# Cannot find printer on WAN

Tags: printer

My HP EliteBook laptop and Cannon MX922 are on the same wireless network but I cannot connect to printer. It works with all my other devices so it is specific to this OS. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed the linux driver from manufacturer page? [MX922 Driver Linux Deb](http://pdisp01.c-wss.com/gdl/WWUFORedirectTarget.do?id=MDEwMDAwNTE3MDAx&cmp=ABR&lang=EN)
During the installation process you can setup the WLAN settings of the printer.

PS: For installation you may need to install a deb-package manager first.

PPS: This should be a comment, but I do not have enough reputations